Bitcoin balance
I downloaded Bitcoin so I could order stuff online. I had money on my cash app. I had to go pick up my kids so my friend said she would purchase it for me using my phone. When I got back I had a confirmation email saying I purchased $50 worth of bitcoin. But when I went on bitcoin I didn't have a balance.I have email verifications for purchase orders. But I also have Bitcoin withdrawals confirmations after the purchase order was completed.but I don't know where it went

Hello, welcome to the bitcoin.stackexchange question & answer website, There are many different software programs for bitcoin, with many different names. From exactly where did you download "Bitcoin" ?
